# How to read csv file with specific quoting with pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have csv file(1.csv) like:

```
[a] [b] [c]
[1] [2,54] ['a
b
c']
[2] [3,45] ['b
c
d']
```

It's valid csv format. How can I read files like this with pandas?
In current state I have:

```
df = pd.read_csv('1.csv', sep=' ', thousands=',')
print(df)
   [a]     [b]  [c]
0  [1]  [2,54]  ['a
1    b     NaN  NaN
2  c']     NaN  NaN
3  [2]  [3,45]  ['b
4    c     NaN  NaN
5  d']     NaN  NaN
```

But don't know how to deal with []. In success read I expect dataframe should be to something like this:

```
print(df)

-----------------
  a b c
0 1 2.54 a\nb\nc
1 2 3.45 b\nc\nd
```

Comment: Why is this question down voted ? He's posted his problem and what he's tried

Comment: I would imagine you would have to write a parsing method which deals with this manually and piece together your data frame from first principles. When I saw this, the first thing I thought of was the `quotechar` parameter in `read_csv`, but that only takes one character and not the set `r'[\[\]]'`. Moreover, there doesn't seem to be a way (though I might just not know) to set `read_csv` to break lines on column modulo rather than `\n`

Answer (score -1):

```
Fast example for one column
```

`pd.read_csv(“file”,sep=“ “,header=None)`
        `df[0]=df[0].str.replace(“[“,””).str.replace(“]”,””)`

Set header

```
df.columns=df.iloc[0]
```